# ActiveRecord Dual Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to create a model that has a collection, of which there may be 0 or 1 "primary" (or default) item in the collection, I'd like to create an attribute that directly references this primary item.

An example model set might look like:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :company

Company < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :users
has_one :primary_user, class: 'User'
```

The "primary" user should be the only result returned by Company.primary_user, but should also be a part of the "users" collection

What are some ways to accomplish this? Reminder, there is only 0 or 1 "primary" allowed, and it must be a member of the general collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

1. In your `company` table add a field called `primary_user_id: integer` with a migration (only if you don't have it, I believe you do). In this field your are going to store the `id` of the primary user for that company. You should set the primary user in the `create` method of the `companies_controller.rb`.
2. In your `Company` model add the method that returns you the primary user.

   ```
   Company < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :users  

     def primary_user
       return User.find(primary_user_id)
     end

   end
   ```
3. Then whenever you want to use this method you should be careful cause you said there could be no `primary_user` for some `companies`. So after calling `primary_user` method verify if it is not `nil`.

   *In any view you got to use this or controller*

   ```
   #bunch of code you got wherever you are

   #i want to get the primary user of my first company
   company = Company.first
   primary_user = company.primary_user

   #in order to access field from primary_user, firstly do this
   #if primary_user exists 

   if !primary_user.nil?

     #do whatever you want with your primary_user
     puts primary_user.name
     primary_user.destroy #don't think you want to destroy him

   end
   ```

Comment: Thanks, nice and simple, and gets me about 90% of the way there, the remainder of which (ensuring the "primary" is in the set of company's users), shouldn't be too tricky. I'll update once I've completed the implementation

Comment: I don't know how you declare a set of users for a company but my approach would be to have a column `company_id` in `users` table. So this field specify the company where the user belongs to. And to ensure if a primary user is in the set of users for the company you should only see its `company_id` field. 
But my advise with this is to be careful where you set the primary user for a company, for example in create or update methods for `company`.

Comment: The `has_many :users` collection is the declaration of the set / collection. I plan that the validation will ensure that any `primary_user` is in the `users` collection, and a to ensure that the `primary_user` is not removed from the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a lambda to `has_one` and use it to scope the relationship:

```
has_one :primary_user, -> { where primary: 1 },  class_name: 'User'
```

This does not enforce that there can be atmost one primary user. That is something you will have to handle elsewhere - eg. through a custom validation.

Comment: Thanks, but the restriction to 0 or 1 is the essential part of this question.

Comment: OK. In that case you will try to process my advise about using custom validation and update the question with the code that you have written but couldn't get to work. I will take a look if I can resolve any issues present there. You may want to start reading here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators